# Stream video from one windows computer to another

Tags: windows-7, video, streaming

I'm looking for a simple method to stream video from one Win7 computer on my home network to another Win7 computer.

Given the following constraints:

- The video being streamed can be any of the common formats and containers.
- Everything is controlled from the sending computer.

  - There should be no need to touch the receiving computer, which is hooked up to a TV.
- No transcoding.

... how can I configure the receiving computer such that it will listen for a stream and, when it receives the stream, show it full screen?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off topic here, please read our [faq]. You might want to check out vlc, it can do this.

Comment: You can use Play-to: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/using-the-play-to-feature-to-stream-media

Comment: @terdon how do you configure a vlc client to play any stream directed at it? All the instructions I see are for the client picking a specific stream to play.

Comment: @BalaSivakumar I hadn't realized WMP would play as many formats and containers, although it does require using codec packs.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html.

Comment: @terdon that's the general streaming documentation link. Do you have a specific link for my use case, as I haven't been able to find it?

Comment: No, sorry, that's why I have only posed comments and not an answer. [This](http://wiki.videolan.org/Streaming/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @terdon that's among the vlc pages that shows how to set up a client to receive a specific stream, rather setting up a client to listen generally for whatever might be sent its way.